# What fiber PCI-E card to buy? HP BL532A MSL4048 1 LTO-5 ULTRIUM 3280 FC 48-SLOT TAPE LIBRARY

Tags: hp, tape, tapedrive

I bought a HP BL532A MSL4048 1 LTO-5 ULTRIUM 3280 FC 48-SLOT TAPE LIBRARY

I have a few quick questions:

1. What is the best fiber card to buy for this unit?
2. Can I buy a quad port fiber card and use 1 of the ports for fast ethernet & the 2 other ports on the same card for the tape library connection?

Comment: Shopping Questions and product recommendations are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Any HP FibreChannel 4Gb or 8Gb HBA will be compatible with your library.](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/storage/saninfrastructure/hba.html)

FibreChannel cards have nothing to do with Ethernet. The library only has 1 FC connection, you couldn't use 2 HBA ports without an intermediate switch (which would only add complexity and another SPoF).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The library has 2 fiber ports. So for this library, should I buy a fiberchannel PCI-E card for my server or an ethernet PCI-E fiber? So, I should only connect the fiber channel card with 1 of the ports, correct?

Comment: I stand corrected, it does have two ports for the one drive. Ethernet still has nothing to do with FibreChannel though. Also, I'm not misspelling "Fibre", it's a European standard, so it's spell with the UK's version, not the US's "Fiber".